# how to add another environment in advanced template

Tags: yii2

I m using yii2 2.0-dev AdvancedTemplate and need to add another environment (**API**),
similar to the currently working **Frontend**, **Backend**.

I tried to copy the files and search trough the settings but there are still some errors
and I feel this is the wrong way to do it...

There should be automated/console way to do this... but I find nothing in the docs.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create folder API in /environments/[prod|dev|other] and call `./init` command

Comment: wellcome to SO! can you provide a reference link for more information?